# PYTHON: Trying to fetch all HREF urls from a site

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch all href urls from this site, mostly trying to get the ones that are included in the clips on the site. Site is https://twitchclip.io/
Here in my screenshot we can see theres a href link to a clip
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwygm.png)

But this is what my debugger prints:
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHWgY.png)

My code:

```
driver.get("https://twitchclip.io/")

elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href]')
for elem in elems:
  print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you actually asking about?

Comment: Please post text as text, not an image of text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is caused by the fact that the website your trying to crawl has its video as `iframe` from twitch. If you want the urls from the videos you need to switch your context to each of the frame, fetch all the urls, get back to the page and repeat each steps so as to get all the urls. If you aslo need the urls on the page, you can fetch the urls before or after looping in the iframes.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Driver initialisation
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Get the website
driver.get("https://twitchclip.io/")

# Find all the iframes in the page
iframes = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")

# Loop in the iframes
for iframe in iframes:
    # Switch to the frame
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    # Get all the urls on the frame
    elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
    for elem in elems:
        print(elem.get_attribute("href"))

    # Go back to the main page
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```